# Python Adapter pattern class takes no arguments error

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns

I am learning the Adapter pattern using a straightforward example, I am facing a **TypeError: ElfAdapter() takes no arguments** when I am trying to add Class as an argument.
WHY...? any ideas?

```
class Elf:
    def null_nin(self):
        print('Elfs says: calling the overlord ...')

class ElfAdapter:
    def __int__(self, elf):
        self.elf = elf

    def call_me(self):
        self.elf.null_nin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    minions = [ElfAdapter(Elf())]

    for minion in minions:
        minion.call_me()
```

Comment: `__init__` not `__int__`

Comment: omg i didn't notice that at all thank u

Answer (score 0):

yeah you just misspelled *init* with *int*, i just did the same mistake and i was searching for the same answers xd